# UITableView Prevent delegate method for subclasses

Tags: ios, iphone, overriding, uitableview

All my `UIViewController`'s are inherited from one ViewController, and the base viewController has a `UITableView` as follows:

BaseViewController.h

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> 

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *menuTableView;
```

BaseViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
_menuTableView =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.......];
_menuTableView.delegate = self;
_menuTableView.dataSource = self;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; ... ETC
```

and In my other viewController:
SPViewController.h

```
@interface SPViewController : BaseViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

    UITableView *myTableView;
}
```

SPViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
myTableView =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(.......];
myTableView.delegate = self;
myTableView.dataSource = self;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; ... ETC
```

Every time i reach the secant `UITableView`, i found that the first (`_menuTableView`) ones data and values and height and action ... etc, is the same as the second one (`myTableView`).

How to prevent the `UITableView` in the class that every other class is inherited form it from calling the subclasses `delegate` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, that's the way OOP works.

You subclass needs to know that the superclass may be calling with a different table view. It should use an `if` statement to check the `tableView` passed to the delegate methods and then either call `super` (and do nothing itself) or run its own logic.

Comment: Not of doing what you ask, but I have told you what you should be doing.

Comment: Well, not no hope - you just need to implement the solution as per @Wain's answer- e.g. `numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { if (tableView == self.myTableView) { return <WHATEVER>} else return ([super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView]) }`

Comment: However, my gut feel tells me that your object model could probably be tweaked.  Move the menu tableView into its own class and then in `BaseViewController` have a property that refers to an instance of that class that implements the table view delegates for the menu

Comment: @Paulw11, I like that suggestion. It would work well if the `BaseViewController` acted as a container view controller (so the other view controller is added with `addChildViewController:`).

Comment: @wain, yes or you can even add it in IB by adding in a view and setting the custom object type - make the `BaseViewController` menuController @property `IBOutlet` and then you can just drag a connection

Comment: @Paulw11, as the `BaseViewController` is a common class it shouldn't have a direct reference to a specific non-common class. Using the container relationship allows that anonymous association cleanly.

Comment: So you needed a little code to understand the approach outlined in my answer?